# Get a list of all locations you have visited via Instagram posts

Tags: geolocation, location, instagram, instagram-api, reverse-geocoding

Is there any way to categorize user's Instagram posts based on location, so you can view all the countries, cities and different location you have visited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an idea to figure out what countries, cities I've visited based on my Instagram posts. I created [Instagram Analyzer](https://github.com/nejckorasa/instagram-analyzer).

It is a Python application that analyses all your Instagram media. It collects location data, uses reverse geocoding provided by LocationIQ and prints locations, countries and cities you've visited so far, as well as how many times.

All data is also stored to local JSON files so it can be used for later individual analysis.